# Scalar Variable Declaration in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am getting the following error when i am trying to check if a password and username is true in the database.

***Here is the following error:***

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@username".

The error is pointing at `string password = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`
I am trying to simply check if the password is correct and assigned to the username input.

***Here is the code so far:***

```
protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "Select count(*) from Student Where Student_Username=@username";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTxt.Text);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();

    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPassword = "Select Student_Password from Student Where Student_Username=@username";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
        string password = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if (password == passwordTxt.Text)
        {
            Session["New"] = usernameTxt.Text;
            Response.Write("corret");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("incorrect");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("username is incorret");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type-o, you forgot the `@`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTxt.Text);
```

Another unrelated concern is that you are not closing your connection in you finally block. If you have a sql exception your connection would stay open, this is not good. The easiest way to fix this is to wrap your connection creation in a using block.

#### Edits

I see some room for improvement here. Everything can really be put into a single db call. To read data back you should really be using a DataReader and not ExecuteScalar.

```
protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var conStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True";
    
    bool userExists = false;
    string password = null;
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "Select Student_Password from Student Where Student_Username=@username";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTxt.Text);
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read()) // if there is a record there is a user so get the password
            {
                userExists = true;
                password = reader.GetString(0); // get string in position 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (userExists)
    {
        if (password == passwordTxt.Text)
        {
            Session["New"] = usernameTxt.Text;
            Response.Write("corret");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("incorrect");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("username is incorret");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah i see that now, i have re run the code and i am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @DonaldBury - I reduced your code to 1 database call. Is the error message the exact same still?

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm. Thanks ever so much for your time and effort in helping me.

Comment: @DonaldBury - one more note. If this is for actual live data (ie. not for school or something fun/personal) you should not store the password as plain text. Instead store a hash of the password and then compare the stored hash to the generated hash of the input to see if they are the same. There are many existing articles on this so I will not bother with that but the chosen hashing algorithm is important so read a recent article because these algorithms are replaced periodically as they become compromised.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `@` in the commands. For sample:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTxt.Text);
```

In the second command, defined by `cmd2` you did not define the `username` argument, for sample:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernameTxt.Text);
string password = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

The `ExecuteScalar` will execute the query and return the value in the first column of the first row. Just it, but it doesn't means that you cannot take a null value. It should be nice if you check if the value is not null before reading the value.

Comment: I have corrected this and realised this small mistake. This is due to testing out what i could change to make it work. But again the error is still pointing at string password = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); and showing the scalar declare error

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@username1".

Comment: Are you sure you have define the right name for the parameter? `username` is not equals `username1`.

Comment: Its all correct. I doubled checked then double checked again